# Raspbian: python requests not working when using 3g connection and NetworkManager

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gsm

I'm trying to setup my Raspberry Pi Zero W to use 3G connection as failover - main connection is WLAN. I'm using ZTE MF627 modem, configured in NetworkManager.
When connection is established, ping -I ppp0 works okay, with 200-300ms delay, even lynx works good, but my POST request via python requests didnt work - timeout. When i switch to WLAN - everything is ok. 
When i use wvdial to establish 3G connection everything was also ok.
What should i do?

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not the right place for networking problems. You might find help at one of our sibling websites.

Comment: what is running on the raspberry pi? OS-wisely

Comment: Raspbian stretch

Comment: After long investigation i found the problem: it was an empty result from server side. When i use WLAN - that wasn't a problem, when i use 3G and HTTPS also, but when i use 3G and HTTP - there was timeout always. I added "OK" response to my backend - and magically everything works. That's weird.